# How to extend CodeIgniter's library?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have followed every rule there is on CI docs page but still get error

> Call to undefined method CI_Form_validation::clear_field_data()

I placed the file MY_Form_validation.php in application/core directory:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function clear_field_data() {

        $this->_field_data = array();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

and then in my controller I load class as usual:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
```

and use my new method:

```
$this->form_validation->clear_field_data();
$this->load->view('product/create', $data);
```

Which are the mistakes in my attempt to extend the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your own libraries must be in the folder: **application/libraries**

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->clear_field_data();
$this->load->view('product/create', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're loading the wrong library? Your lib should also go in `application/libraries`.

```
$this->load->library('MY_Form_validation');

$this->MY_Form_validation->clear_field_data();
$this->load->view('product/create', $data);
```